# Show that $(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix}) = 2 + 2\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

A level FP2 question I got stuck on. Please help!

Show that $$(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix}) = 2 + 2\cos x$$

Comment: Just multiply it out and use Euler's formula.

Comment: well e^i + 1 = 0, so i can kinda see where the two comes from, but i dont know about the 2cosx

Comment: @copper.hat Please can you show me. I'm not too sure on how to use Euler's formula sorry.

Comment: What do you mean? Euler's formula just says $e^{it} = \cos t  +i \sin t$. Multiply the above and expand the remaining exponential terms with this formula and that will give the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix})=1+e^{-ix}+e^{ix}+1$

$=2+e^{-ix}+e^{ix}$
$=2+2\cfrac{e^{-ix}+e^{ix}}{2}$
$=2+2\cos(x)$

Comment: Thank you very much that's perfect :)

Comment: 2 minutes sorry wont let me

Answer (score 1):

The Euler formula states that : $$e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$$ And : $$e^{-ix}=cos(x)-isin(x)$$ Also remember that : $$sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$z \bar{z}=||z||^2$$

If $z=1+e^{ix}$ then $\bar{z}=1+e^{-ix}$

$$(1+e^{ix})(1+e^{-ix})=||1+e^{ix}||^2=(1+\cos{x})^2+\sin^2{x}=2+2\cos{x}$$